# Python socket.getsockopt always returns 1 for TCP_WINDOW_CLAMP

Tags: python, sockets

I'm trying to set the `TCP_WINDOW_CLAMP` option on my socket

```
In [1]: import socket
In [2]: sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
In [3]: sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.TCP_WINDOW_CLAMP, 1000000)
```

However when I check that this has been set properly I always get a value of one.

```
In [4]: sock.getsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.TCP_WINDOW_CLAMP)
Out[4]: 1
```

Is this some flag or special value?

#### Edit: Platform

I'm running Anaconda Python on Ubuntu 14.04

```
$ python
Python 3.4.4 |Anaconda 2.3.0 (64-bit)| (default, Jan 11 2016, 13:54:01) 
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-1)] on linux
```

Comment: Are you sure that this option uses `SOL_SOCKET`, not `SOL_TCP`? Getting those mixed up has bitten me before, and the docs are pretty vague.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it looks like the docs are clear on this one, and the guess I posted in a comment is correct -- in the tcp(7) man page, right above the description of `TCP_WINDOW_CLAMP` it says:

> To set or get a TCP socket option, call getsockopt(2) to read  or  setsockopt(2)  to  write  the option with the option level argument set to
>   `IPPROTO_TCP`.

So you need to replace `socket.SOL_SOCKET` with `socket.IPPROTO_TCP` (which is apparently the same as `socket.SOL_TCP`, at least on linux -- not sure what the difference between those is). Right now you're messing with some unrelated other option in the `SOL_SOCKET` namespace that happens to have the same number assigned to it as `TCP_WINDOW_CLAMP`, hence the wildly confusing result.